# Chaining in a command line several tranformations with options

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

My command line utility should accept several filters attached to each other (similar to Unix pipeline).

Each filter has a number of options. For example `chain` filter currently has the following options:

```
  -t NAMESPACE, --target NAMESPACE
                        target namespace(s)
  -s {precedence,doc}, --next-script {precedence,doc}
                        "next script" algorithm ("precedence" is not
                        supported)
  -n {ignore,remove,error}, --not-in-target {ignore,remove,error}
                        what if a result is not in target NS
  -u URL, --universal-precedence URL
                        universal precedence
  -W {inverseofsum,sumofinverses}, --weight-formula {inverseofsum,sumofinverses}
                        formula for weighting scripts
```

How to represent in command arguments the workflow of filters?

The first thought is to use a JSON array. But JSON is not quite a good format for a command line.

The next thought is to separate the filters with some separator. It may be `--` or `--separator` or like this. But `--` is already taken to separate command line options from other command line arguments, and `--separator` does not look good.

Another trouble is that while I use Python 3 `argparse`, this package seems not to be well-suited for several subcommands chained in one command line, like:

```
boiler script filter1 --separator \
  chain -t http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml -n error --separator \
  transformation filter2 --arg x=y --separator \
  transformation filter3
```

Here I attempt to chain four filter subcommands: `script`, `chain`, `tranformation`, `tranformation`. But Python `argparse` (seemingly) does not support having several subcommands in one command line.

So if not `argparse` then what library to use to process command lines like this?

My questions:

1. What are possible user-friendly formats for such command lines?
2. How to parse it with Python `argparse`?
3. If not `argparse`, then what instead?

Also take note, that in the future I may decide to rewrite my software in some other language ([D](https://dlang.org), probably) than Python.

Comment: By default `argparse` parses `sys.argv[1:]`.  Instead you could split that list on your `separator`, and feed each sublist to a parser.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought on this. But for example, if the separator is `+` and the user want to process the file named `+`, what to do?

Comment: @hpaulj Also: How to pass to `argparse` these arguments which go before the first subcommand (the options for the entire pipeline rather than an individual filter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipeline should be provided as a single argument (with possible spaces in it, e.g. using shell quoting) of my program.

The pipeline could be split into several filters by `+`s that is by `\s+\+\s+` regexp. However while splitting quoted `+` (`\+`) shall be ignored.

Then every filter is processed as a separate command line (e.g. using `argparse`). Before passing to `argparse` every filter shall be split on whytespace.

Also, `\` quotes whitespaces (so that the filter is not split at this space) and itself (`\\`).

Note that providing the pipeline as a single argument is hinted by calling shell pipelines like `sh -c 'tr a-z A-Z | tac'` (here the pipeline is a single argument of `sh` program).

Comment: Hm, better to use `+` or `|`?