# Splitting a string into parts (with regexps?)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, parsing, split

The question originating from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53750697/856090 answer.

We receive an "input" string.

The input string is split into several "commands" by `+`s that is by `\s+\+\s+` regexp. However while splitting quoted `+` (`\+`) shall be ignored.

Every command is then split into several "arguments" by whitespace characters, but quoted (`\`) whitespace is not counted on splitting and instead becomes a part of an argument.

Quoted `\` (that is `\\`) becomes regular characted `\` and itself is not participated in quoting.

My solution is to process the input string char-by-char with special behavior for `\`, `+`, and whitespace characters. This is slow and not elegant. I ask for an alternative solution (such as by using regexps).

I write in Python 3.

---

For example,

```
filter1 + \
chain -t http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml -n error + \
transformation filter2 --arg x=y
```

transformation filter3

becomes

```
[['filter1'],
 ['chain', '-t', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', '-n', 'error'],
 ['transformation', 'filter2', '--arg', 'x=y']]
```

and

```
a \+ b + c\ d
```

becomes

```
 [['a', '+', 'b'], ['c d']]
```

Comment: Please give an example of input and expected output (which you wish to get after splitting).

Comment: @hygull examples added

Comment: If no one solves, I will try to solve, actually I am in mobile right now. Got it.Thank you.

Comment: Finally, I solved your problem in mobile at rextester. Crazy exciting question. I am writing answer now. Thank you.

Comment: What if you will get   `[['a', '+', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` in place of `[['a', '+', 'b'], ['c d']]`. Actually, both contains spaces for separation after 1st split operation, or we will need to pass extra parameters for this kind of operation.  I have also tried to obtain 2nd result,  I got but it failed for 1st, so I guessed that we may need extra parameters for that. So I think, if you wish or if my suggested O/P is okay then I will edit or I will try other methods to solve. Thank you.

Comment: @hygull I don't understand wording of your comment. If you mean that `[['a', '+', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` in place of `[['a', '+', 'b'], ['c d']]` is OK, then no, it is not OK

Comment: Okay,  so let me look for more options, thanks for the update.

Comment: @parton, I have updated my code based on your provided input set, please check. Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your problem.

> Here the function **get_splitted_strings_for()** takes 1 parameter of type string **s**, and splits 1 by 1, 2 times and finally it stores result in 2d list.

```
import re

def get_splitted_strings_for(s): 
    splits = []
    splits1 = re.split(r"\s*\+\s+\\\s*|\s+\+\s+", s)

    for split in splits1: 
        if "\+" in split: 
            split = split.replace("\\",  "") 
            splits.append(split.split()) 
        elif "\\" in split: 
            splits.append([split.replace("\\", "")]) 
        else: 
            arr = re.split(r"\s+", split.replace("\\", '')) 
            splits.append(arr) 

    return splits

s = "filter1 + \ chain -t http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml -n error + \ transformation filter2 --arg x=y"
print(get_splitted_strings_for(s))

# [['filter1'], ['chain', '-t', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', '-n', 'error'], ['transformation', 'filter2', '--arg', 'x=y']]

print()  # New line

s2 = "a \+ b + c\ d"
print(get_splitted_strings_for(s2))
# [['a', '+', 'b'], ['c d']]
```

Comment: Wrong! It should be `[['a', '+', 'b'], ['c d']]`

Comment: Okay sorry for that,  let me fix that. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to get 2nd  output in several ways but I got spaces in the substrings. So I suggest if `[['a', '+', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` will help you then it will be better otherwise it introduces extra parameters in function's argument list which again needs more input from your side. Currently, I have updated my answer for this only. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand you: "help you then it will be better otherwise it introduces extra parameters". What does that mean?

Comment: I think that is not required, let me try in other ways. Thank you.

Comment: Based on your provided input set, I have re-tried to look  and updated my code. Now it works for both of your input set. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Your code parses `r'a\\ \+  b + c\ d'` wrongly. It should output `[['a\\', '+', 'b'], ['c d', '+']]`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own version of the routine:

```
import re


def split_pipeline(s):
    res = [['']]
    r = r'\\\\|\\\+|\\\s|\s+\+\s+|\s+|[^\s\\]+'
    for m in re.finditer(r, s, re.M|re.S):
        if m[0][0] == '\\':
            res[-1][-1] += m[0][1:]
        elif re.match(r'^\s+\+\s+$', m[0], re.M|re.S):
            res.append([''])
        elif re.match(r'^\s+$', m[0], re.M | re.S):
            res[-1].append('')
        else:
            res[-1][-1] += m[0]
    return res

print(split_pipeline(r'a\\ \+  b + c\ d'))
# [['a\\', '+', 'b'], ['c d']]
```